# why i have this error "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

// here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Todos extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      this.props.todos.map(todo => {
        <h1>{todo.title}</h1>
      })
    )
  }
}
```

export default Todos;

Answer (score 2):

You map function isn't returning anything. Remove the curly braces, like so:

```
class Todos extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      this.props.todos.map(todo => <h1>{todo.title}</h1>)
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: @LeartMorina no worries :) if you're problem is solved please mark this as the correct answer